# Как сделать вертикальный пикер в Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, datepicker

Как сделать вертикальный пикер как на картинке?

[image: вертикальный пикер]

Может быть есть какая-нибудь готовая библиотека для этого? Или нужно делать свою custom view ? Буду признателен за любую помощь!

Comment: вариантов на Github [большое количество](https://github.com/search?q=android+number+picker)

Comment: возможно подправить что то в библиотеке, например вместо полосок сделать прямоугольник